# How to change a navbar item link

Tags: php, hyperlink, yii

I have this PHP application with set navigation bar items that I want to add to them the item "Tutorial"
[navigation bar items with the one I need to add "tutorial"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPASk.png)

The themes/layout directory has 2 files "admin" and "main" where I found the following code part that belong to the navbar

```
<?php echo Nav::widget([
                'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
                'encodeLabels' => false,
                'items' => [
                    ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Dashboard'), 'url' => ['/dashboard'],
                        'active' => 'app' === $moduleID && 'dashboard' === $controllerID],
                    ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Tutorial'), 'url' => ['/tutorial'],
                    'active' => 'app' === $moduleID && 'tutorial' === $controllerID],
```

I was able to create a placeholder for Turotial in the navigation bar as shown in the code above and I need to link it to an external page like *google.com* instead of a page within the application.
I tried changing the **'url' => ['/tutorial']** parameter but it always direct to an error page and the link has the application url appended to whatever I put after the **/** so it looks like this: *https://mywebsite.com/tutorial*  or *https://mywebsite.com/google.com*
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer through searching indirectly. the answer was simply to remove the [/] and just put the url between '' so it looks like this:

```
['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Tutorial'), 'url' => 'MY URL EXAMPLE',
                'active' => 'app' === $moduleID && 'tutorial' === $controllerID],
```

I also wanted to have it open in new tab so found that the right addition should be ***'linkOptions' => array('target' => '_blank')***
so the whole code looks like this now:

```
['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Tutorial'), 'url' => 'MY URL EXAMPLE',
                        'linkOptions' => array('target' => '_blank'),
                        'active' => 'app' === $moduleID && 'tutorial' === $controllerID],
```

Thank you for hosting me and I hope I added value to this amazing platform